# Change repository on your folder with TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I accidentally created a repository without the default folders in TortoiseSVN then did a checkout locally.  Realized hey, I forgot to create that repository with the defaults so I deleted the repository using VisualSVN Server and then recreated the same repository name which now has the default folders trunk, etc.

Problem is, my local folder has already been checked out.  How can I change it/repoint to the new repository URL?

Answer (score 107):

You can right click on the folder, and click "relocate" in the Tortoise menu.

Comment: Surely this won't actually work in this case? His repository structure has changed, he doesn't just want to move the repository somewhere else.

Comment: Sure he can relocate it to the trunk folder.

Comment: I tried to relocate to the new URL but said there is conflicting UID

Comment: In that case, you may need to create a new folder, check out the files, then manually copy the files you have updated to this new folder.

Comment: Looks like the latest version of Tortoise SVN doesn't have this option any more - any other suggestions?

Comment: @Hippyjim The option is there now.

Comment: If the option does not appear in the context menu, you will need to check the Settings/General/Context Menus. The menu option does not appear to be available by default.

Comment: @Hippyjim also make sure that you right-click on working copy roots. THe context menu is only shown for your working copy roots.

Answer (score 18):

You can right click your working copy and select TortoiseSVN/Switch...
Then change the "To path:" to the new folder in the repository.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

You won't be able to do this easily, as the two repositories don't have the same unique identifier (UID).  There are 2 ways you could have done this:

1. Force a particular UID on the new repository (not sure if your SVN server gives that option)
2. Don't delete the repository, just create the folders in your working copy, and `svn move` the files into trunk, then check the whole thing in.

Comment: To the first way to solve this: If you have access to the server I would add that at the_repo/db/ is a file without extension with the name of UUID that can be replaced with the UUID you need. I would recommend to do a backup previous to the change though.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't have any files in the checked out version that you need, just delete the directory and checkout again.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you have files in your local working copy): Since you created a new repository, I guess you have to import your working copy into the repository.

Using TortoiseSVN, you can export your working copy to a different folder (so that you only have your source files, without the .svn folders). Then you can import that folder into /trunk of your new repository.

Comment: maybe I should just delete every .svn folder and try again from scratch

Comment: meaning there's an svn folder in every sub folder of the affected folder that I'm talking about.  If I delete all the sub svn folders within it, I assume it's essentially like clearing source control from that folder and its sub folders manually?

Comment: I ended up simply deleting the .svn folder in the main directory (the one I originally clicked on and chose check-out) which allowed me to just clear and start over again.

Comment: I ended up fixing exactly as you did, by deleting the .svn folder and re-checking out